# Criar Options com div e fazer interação com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Preciso criar algo parecido com um opiton usando div e sapan, que contenham imagens como ícones, e ainda ter uma interação com JavaScript. Meu código funciona assim, se vier algum idioma do servidor o select e preenchido automaticamente, e é desabilitado. Tenho três opções de idiomas, e apenas dois podem ser selecionados. Minha principal dificuldade é na hora de interagir com o JavaScript. Já tenho um JavaScript pronto mas não sei como posso alterar para funcionar com div e span

```
<div class="divIdiomas" ng-show="vm.form.selectIdioma">
<label class="idioma">{{'MSG.IDIOMAS'| translate}}</label>
<div class="idiomaescolha1">
    <select ng-model="vm.form.produto.idioma1" id="idioma1" class="campoHora input-lg">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="POR" style="background-image:url('/assets/images/flags/4x3/br.svg');" aria-hidden="true">{{'MSG.PORTUGUES'| translate}}</option>
        <option value="ESP" style="background-image:url('/assets/images/flags/4x3/es.svg');" aria-hidden="true">{{'MSG.ESPANHOL'| translate}}</option>
        <option value="ING" style="background-image:url('/assets/images/flags/4x3/us.svg');" aria-hidden="true">{{'MSG.INGLES'| translate}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="idiomaescolha2" ng-show="vm.form.produto.temIdioma">
    <select ng-model="vm.form.produto.idioma2" id="idioma2" class="campoHora input-lg">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="POR"  style="background-image:url('/assets/images/flags/4x3/br.svg');" aria-hidden="true">{{'MSG.PORTUGUES'| translate}}</option>
        <option value="ESP"  style="background-image:url('/assets/images/flags/4x3/es.svg');" aria-hidden="true">{{'MSG.ESPANHOL'| translate}}</option>
        <option value="ING"  style="background-image:url('/assets/images/flags/4x3/us.svg');" aria-hidden="true">{{'MSG.INGLES'| translate}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
function getIdiomas() {
vm.form.produto.temIdioma = false;
if ((vm.form.produto.codigo === "2") || (vm.form.produto.codigo === "3")) {
    vm.form.selectIdioma = true;
    vm.form.produto.idioma1 = '';
    vm.form.produto.idioma2 = '';
    var selecionado = $('#horaPasseios :selected').text();
    if (selecionado) {                    
        for (var i = 0; i < vm.form.listaHorarios.length; i++) {
            if (((vm.form.listaHorarios[i].H_INI).substring(0, 5)) == selecionado) {
                if (vm.form.listaHorarios[i].I_1) {
                    vm.form.produto.temIdioma = true;
                    vm.form.produto.idioma1 = vm.form.listaHorarios[i].I_1
                    document.getElementById("idioma1").disabled = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    vm.form.produto.temIdioma = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (vm.form.produto.temIdioma) {
            for (var i = 0; i < vm.form.listaHorarios.length; i++) {
                if (((vm.form.listaHorarios[i].H_INI).substring(0, 5)) == selecionado) {
                    if (vm.form.listaHorarios[i].I_2) {
                        if (vm.form.listaHorarios[i].I_2 == vm.form.listaHorarios[i].I_1) {
                            vm.form.produto.temIdioma2 = false
                            break;
                        } else {
                            vm.form.produto.temIdioma2 = true;
                            vm.form.produto.idioma2 = vm.form.listaHorarios[i].I_2
                            document.getElementById("idioma2").disabled = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        vm.form.produto.temIdioma2 = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!vm.form.produto.temIdioma2) {
                for (var i = 0; i < vm.form.listaHorarios.length; i++) {
                    if (((vm.form.listaHorarios[i].H_INI).substring(0, 5)) == selecionado) {
                        var select = document.getElementById("idioma2");
                        for (var j = 0; j < select.length; j++) {
                            if (select[j].value == vm.form.listaHorarios[i].I_1) {
                                select.remove(j)
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    vm.form.selectIdioma = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Cara, que eu saiba, o pessoal lê os options gerados dinamicamente no html, os interpreta e troca o <select> por <div> ou por <ul> com um estilo que faz parecer uma lista suspensa. Dá uma pesquisada nesse sentido. Que eu saiba, não tem essa opção de ícones no option.

Comment: Mas do jeito que está na sua pergunta funciona tudo direitinho?

Comment: Veja se a outra solução na minha resposta lhe atende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quanto a pergunta `Existe algo que posso usar para substituir o option do select, preciso fazer um select que que tenha imagens(ícones)`

a resposta é **existe sim**

**Exemplo**

```css
.select-sim {
  width:200px;
  height:22px;
  line-height:22px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position:relative;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.select-sim::after {
  content:"▼";
  font-size:0.5em;
  font-family:arial;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:5px;
  transform:translate(0, -50%);
}

.select-sim:hover::after {
  content:"";
}

.select-sim:hover {
  overflow:visible;
}

.select-sim:hover .options .option label {
  display:inline-block;
}

.select-sim:hover .options {
  background:white;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;
  left:-1px;
  width:100%;
  height:88px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.select-sim .options .option {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.select-sim:hover .options .option {
  height:22px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.select-sim .options .option img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.select-sim .options .option label {
  display:none;
}

.select-sim .options .option input {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  /* fix specific for Firefox */
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
}

.select-sim .options .option input:checked + label {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

.select-sim:hover .options .option input + label {
  display:block;
}

.select-sim:hover .options .option input:checked + label {
  background:#fffff0;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-sim" id="select-color">
  <div class="options">
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="color" value="" id="color-" checked />
      <label for="color-">
        Selecione
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" id="color-red" />
      <label for="color-red">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3aQy.png" alt="" /> {{'MSG.PORTUGUES'| translate}}
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" id="color-green" />
      <label for="color-green">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sd09.png" alt="" /> {{'MSG.ESPANHOL'| translate}}
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="color-blue" />
      <label for="color-blue">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw8mK.png" alt="" /> {{'MSG.INGLES'| translate}}
      </label>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fonte - brother Alvaro Montoro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list/41189982#41189982)

---

> **Sobre a interação com o script já é outro capitulo e você não precisa mudar option por div e span :)**

Veja exemplo com options e imagens [**aqui**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/Criar-Options-com-div-e-fazer-interacao-com-JavaScript.htm)

> Se o problema era os options, creio que dessa forma seu script deva funcionar:

**Biblioteca:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <msdropdown> -->
<script src="jquery.dd.js"></script>
<link href="dd.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- </msdropdown> -->
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="vm.form.produto.idioma1" id="idioma1" class="select" style="width: 300px">
      <option value="">{{'MSG.IDIOMAS'| translate}}</option>
      <option value='POR' data-image="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3aQy.png" data-imagecss="flag br" data-title="Brazil">
        {{'MSG.PORTUGUES'| translate}}l</option>
      <option value='ESP' data-image="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sd09.png" data-imagecss="flag es" data-title="Spain">
        {{'MSG.ESPANHOL'| translate}}</option>
      <option value='ING' data-image="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw8mK.png" data-imagecss="flag us" data-title="United States">
        {{'MSG.INGLES'| translate}}</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<div class="idiomaescolha2" ng-show="vm.form.produto.temIdioma">
<select ng-model="vm.form.produto.idioma2" id="idioma2" class="select" style="width: 300px">
      <option value="">{{'MSG.IDIOMAS'| translate}}</option>
      <option value='POR' data-image="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3aQy.png" data-imagecss="flag br" data-title="Brazil">
        {{'MSG.PORTUGUES'| translate}}l</option>
      <option value='ESP' data-image="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sd09.png" data-imagecss="flag es" data-title="Spain">
        {{'MSG.ESPANHOL'| translate}}</option>
      <option value='ING' data-image="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw8mK.png" data-imagecss="flag us" data-title="United States">
        {{'MSG.INGLES'| translate}}</option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $(".select").msDropdown({roundedBorder:false});
});
```

**arquivos msdropdown no github**

[jquery.dd.js](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown/blob/master/js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.js)

[dd.css](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown/blob/master/css/msdropdown/dd.css)

Comment: Meu principal problema é com o script.

Comment: @ErickZanetti, nesse caso sugiro reformular a pergunta